# Azure Get Certificate in Power Shell

Tags: powershell, azure

Trying to list all the certificates in my account.

When using `Get-AzureCertificate`, it complains I need to select default subscription with `Select-AzureSubscription`.
But no subscription can be selected with `Select-AzureSubscription`,
I can only select subscription with `Select-AzureRmSubscription`. But this `Get-AzureCertificate` needs `Select-AzureSubscription`.

How do I list all certificates in my Azure with PowerShell?

Comment: which version of your Azure PowerShell?  Please run this script to check it `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`, also does other command run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you log in to an ASM subscription? Looks like you have logged in using Add-AzureRMAccount or Login-AzureRMAccount. Use Add-AzureAccount instead.

Comment: I did try `Add-AzureAccount` but my subscription is not listed and it tells me I'm not an Administrator or co-Admin. When I login to my Azure Portal, I can see subscriptions and all the certificates. What's the diff between `Login-AzureRmAccount` and `Add-AzureAccount` anyway?